# Recovering signals in the presence of noise

Tags: noise

Suppose you have a transmission line carrying a digital signal and the line is picking up random noise such that half the bits in the original signal are randomly flipped before they reach the receiver. What techniques are available to recover such a corrupted signal?

Comment: > "...half the bits in the original signal are randomly flipped before they reach the receiver" 

That is a _tough_ channel to be working on. Here are two strategies.

 - If you know which bits were flipped by the channel, just unflip them.

 - Ignore the received signal completely and just toss a fair coin repeatedly to regenerate the bits at the receiver. What you get as the output will be just as good a result as any other generated by more elaborate means.

Comment: @DilipSarwate:In this case you don't know which bits were flipped because they were flipped by truly random noise.

Comment: In that case, you are SOL unless you choose to follow my second suggestion, flippant (or unflippant?) though it is. A channel with a bit error rate of 50% has **zero capacity** and effectively there is little that one can do to get any useful information from it. If you _know_ which bits are incorrect even if you don't know whether there were 0's or 1's in those positions, then you have gotten 50% of the data (on average) through correctly, but in the absence of this, guessing works as well as anything else you might do, and is a lot cheaper to boot.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thanks, but what does SOL mean ?

Comment: SOL = sheer out of luck.

Comment: lol; a sophisticated European gentleman such a yourself using common American slang, well I'm disappointed to say the least ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the compliment but, alas, I am not sophisticated, not European, and not a gentleman. Surely you don't mean to tell me that the S in SOL does not stand for Sheer, heh heh?  Oh well, live and learn....

Answer (score 0):

Information will have been lost due to the noise.  You either need to know enough about the lost information (or the exact noise sequence) via other means (resend, side channel or a priori, etc.), or via massive redundancy that you know was originally in the signal in a known encoding (ECC), to have some good statistical chance of reconstructing (some of) the lost data.

Comment: Could you recommend a code that will allow one to combat a 50% bit error rate on the channel? As the OP says in a response to another answer, repetition coding is not allowed, and, as far as I can tell, any other kind of encoding might not be permitted either.

Answer (score -1):

Repeat the message. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_averaging

Blablabla, answer was too short. :-)

Comment: You are not allowed to repeat the message. The question was "how can I recover the information" , not "what do I do if I can't recover the information :-)